# Ajax POSt not working in IE11

Tags: ajax, redirect, yii2, internet-explorer-11

I have a button in my webpage which calls an ajax method a s below

```
    $.ajax({
        cache: false,
        type:'POST',
        data: 'type='+userType +'&user='+user ,
        url:' ".\yii\helpers\Url::to([$program.'/'.$url.'/setcustomer/'])."     ', 
        success: function(data) {
            console.log('Hii');
            $('#phoneErr').html(data);                            
        }
    });
```

This works in all browsers except IE11
I get the following error when i click on the button:

```
SCRIPT7002: XMLHttpRequest: Network Error 0x800c0008, The download of the    specified resource has failed.
```

Has anyone faced this issue and what is the solution to this?

There is a redirection in my PHP code in the setcustomer action. Can this issue be related to it?

My ajax response body says Key  Value
Response    HTTP/1.1 302 Found
and not actually redirecting to the required page
is the problem related to IE ajax cannot handle 302 redirect within an ajax response as success.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Yii2 jQuery not working in IE11](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/30351338/yii2-jquery-not-working-in-ie11)

Comment: if it is due to url prepend like stated in the above link it should not be working in other browsers as well? or something is different in IE11?

Answer (score 0):

I make the next solution:

in js:

```
$(document).ajaxComplete(function (event, xhr, settings) {
    var url = xhr && xhr.getResponseHeader('X-Redirect');
    if (url) {
        window.location = url;
    }
});
```

in php (yii2) (ie not understand 302 via ajax, we send 200) :

```
$this->redirect(['index', 'id' => $model->id], 200);
```